# Various View-panes with arguments from url in the same panel-page. It is possible?

Tags: panels, 7, views

I'm making a web about football and this is the situation of my problem:

I have a content-type called 'player stats' taxonomized with the vocabularies 'season' & 'day' and another content-type called 'chronicle' with the same tag-system of the 'player stats' content-type.

I want to have my custom node-template for all the content of type 'Chronicle', but including in any content-pane a Views-pane with content from the 'player stats' for a given 'season' and a given 'day'. My url structure is: example.com/chronicle/season-x/day-y and I tried to get arguments from url but the internal path node/% impossibilite it (as far I know)...

My second option is to create a Panel page, and try to insert content (using views pane's with contextual filters) from both content-types 'chronicle' and 'player stats' to make a chronicle with complete stats of the players in the same page. But my problem is that I only get visible ONE View-pane, the other ones seems not to work an I can't see any more view-panes that compose my panel-page. (please, see attached snapshots)

I am doing anything wrong? I'll glad to read you suggestions and your help.
(sorry for my bad english, I'm catalonian from Barcelona). Thanks.

Attached files::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

It's my first time posting here, so I have not enough privilieges to attach more than 2 links. But snapshots & export-files are available in the original post, at drupal.org:

- http://drupal.org/node/1392700

Comment: Greetings, I just visited Barcelona with my daughter this summer.  It is a wonderful city! I think we need some more information to answer you. Do you have pathauto enabled? I tried looking at your export, but am a bit confused (no spanish).  Please explain what you have the context filter set for in one of the panes.  What type of content and the 'settings if no context is found'. Also any relationships.  My first impression is that the context filter is not set to read the URL correctly.  We can probably figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion has gotten long in the issue queue already, so instead of repeating what's been said there, I'm try to explain from scratch how you can have two Views in the same Page, with the same arguments.

1. Create two Views. In both Views, add *only* a single "Content pane" display. **No page displays**.
2. Configure your contextual filters on both content panes, make sure they expect the same type of argument.
3. In the pane-specific settings, set both panes to get their arguments from context, pick appropriate context objects.
4. Create a new custom page, or use an existing one. Add both content panes.
5. Done.

Additional comments: I guess the settings of both Views have more similarites than their arguments, so I would put both of the content panes into one View.

Comment: Gotta love that 4 _years_ after posting this answer, I get my first up vote.